# Using X11 Displays through Terminal.app commands : generic mapping tools

Tags: bash, terminal, x11, ghostscript

I am trying to figure out why I can't use ghostscript or ghostview (or any other X11 applications) when I try to call them in the Terminal.  I am using `bash`, and I also used Fink to get the packages I need.  I am using GMT (generic mapping tools), and the commands within this `gmt` package that don't need x11 run perfectly fine, but when I try to display a postscript, using either the command `$ gs` or `$ gv`, I get these error messages, respectively:

`gv: Unable to open the display.` and `GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Cannot open X display ':0'.`
`**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.`

I have tried many edits that I've found online, such as adding editing the `~./profile`, as shown below:

```
test -r /sw/bin/init.sh && . /sw/bin/init.sh

. /sw/bin/init.sh
export DISPLAY=:0
```

The saving grace here is that if I run the same commands from `gmt` in xterm (the terminal in X11), the graphic I need is created just fine.  All I want to do is have X11 called through the terminal, but right now, I cannot get it working.